# Нужна помощь со слайдером

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slider

Здравствуйте. Пишу слайдер-карусель. Возникла проблема. Он не адаптировался под разрешение экрана. Проблему исправил путем js но теперь при изменении размеров окна браузера конструкция ломается. Подскажите, как заставить из функции ресайза передавать значение в функцию слайдера и делать это каждый раз при ресайзе.

```js
var width = $('.sliders-container').width();
$(document).ready(function slider() {
  var screen = $(window).width();

  $('.slider>li').width(width);
  $('.slider').width(width * $('.slider>li').length);


  $('.slider').css('left', -width);
  $('.slider>li:last-child').appendTo('.slider');

  function nextSlide() {
    $('.slider').animate({
      'margin-left': -width
    }, 500, function() {
      $('.slider>li:first-child').appendTo('.slider');
      $('.slider').css('margin-left', 0);
    });
  }

  function prevSlide() {
    $('.slider').animate({
      'margin-left': width
    }, 500, function() {
      $('.slider>li:last-child').prependTo('.slider');
      $('.slider').css('margin-left', 0);
    });
  }

  $('.next').click(nextSlide);
  $('.prev').click(prevSlide);

  $(window).resize(function resize() {
    var screen = $(window).width();
    $('.slider>li').css('width', screen);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sliders-container">
  <ul class="slider">
    <li>
      <img class="slider-item" src="IMG/1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="slider-caption">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="slider-item" src="IMG/2.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="slider-caption">
        <h3>Quidem, eius, minima.</h3>
        <p>Tempora facilis voluptatibus neque libero corrupti, aliquam est.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="slider-item" src="IMG/3.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="slider-caption">
        <h3>Exercitationem, nam, est.</h3>
        <p>Nesciunt, a eveniet totam explicabo, vitae dolorem eum?</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="prev">&#10094</div>
  <div class="next">&#10095</div>

  <div class="dots">
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В jQuery есть метод `.resize()` - https://api.jquery.com/resize/. Но я бы лучше использовал `css` для адаптивности.

```
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        $( ".slider" )......;
    });
```

Comment: Используйте  media-css , и адаптируйте под разные разрешения

Comment: Проблема как я думаю именно в моем желании сделать карусель адаптивной. По умолчанию как видно в скрипте, контейнер равен ширине слайда, умноженного на количество. Видимая область же равна слайду, но также я хочу сделать ее адаптивной. width 100% как сразу понятно, тянет контейнер на всю область ленты карусели. Потому и такие заморочки с jQuery.